# Blender don't see my GPU Nvidia Geforce 820m, why?

Tags: rendering, gpu

Why is this happening and how to understand which card suits Blender and which one does not?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks Nvidia didn’t enable CUDA on the 820m. https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus

Until blender 3.x with vulkan support try using OpenCL kernel. Should be faster for now!